# I want to make function().action(); in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

sorta like jquery but I wanna make a function in js with a **.whatever** at the end, for example `function().text()` or something like that what I've tried to do is

```
function a() {

    function click() {
        alert("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what problem do you have exactly in implementing it?

Comment: I can't get in to look like that and function

Comment: Show a [mcve] of what you have tried. What does the `function()` return?  And why do you expect that what you return from `function()` has a function `text` that can be called.

Comment: you can call `a().b()` if `a` returns an object containing a function named `b`

Comment: Did you look into how jQuery does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"function" is a reserved word so you can't use that as a function name. You could create a function with a different name such as "foo". It needs to return an object with the key "whatever" which is another function that you can call and do something with.

For example:

```js
function foobar (){
 const foo = {}
    foo.whatever = function (){
     console.log('foobar')
    }
    return foo
}


foobar().whatever()
```